# Style CheckboxSelectMultiple form field. Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form which has one checkboxselectmultiple field:

```
class CreateRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('name', 'image', 'description', 'cooking_time', 'tags')
        widgets = {
            ...
            'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            ...
        }
```

I can iterate through field's options like:

```
{% for option in form.tags %}
{{ option.tag }} {{ option.choice_label }}
{% endfor %}
```

How would I render `{{ option.tag }}` as an input field? i.e:

```
<input type="checkbox"...>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact after reading some django docs on this topic I understood that that the fields of `CheckboxSelectMultiple` are already rendered as `input` fields. So if you don't need to add specific values to each field you can do it straight in form by adding attrs to widget:

```
widgets = {
            ...
            'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'anyclass'}),
            ...
          }
```

But if you need to add different parameters to each field you can do it in template this way:

```
                        {% for obj_choice, obj_value in form.obj.field.choices %}
                            <div class="tags__item">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="{{obj_choice.instance.pk}}"
                                id="id_{{obj_choice.instance.value}}" 
                                class="tags__checkbox tags__checkbox_style_{{obj_choice.instance.style}}">
                                <label for="id_{{obj_choice.instance.value}}" class="tags__label">
                                    {{obj_choice.instance.template_name}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```